Target not created in keil
Although I checked in header file, GPIO_SetMode is already defined.
void GPIO_SetMode(GPIO_T *port, uint32_t u32PinMask, uint32_t u32Mode);

linking...
.\obj\template.axf: Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol GPIO_SetMode (referred from main.o).
Not enough information to list image symbols.
Not enough information to list load addresses in the image map.
Finished: 2 information, 0 warning and 1 error messages.
".\obj\template.axf" - 1 Error(s), 0 Warning(s).
Target not created.
Build Time Elapsed:  00:00:01

How to remove this error?

Does this answer your question? When including headers in a C program, how does the linker/compiler find the corresponding code?

That is not the "definition" of the function in the header file.  That is the "declaration" (or function prototype).

The code you posted is a declaration not a definition.  The error is a linker error.  You have not included the source definition in your project.

From what library is GPIO_SetMode coming from? Such things are target specific and not defined by Keil.  Normally defined and provided by the MCU vendor or third-party support, or even defined by you.  Keil dev-packs include MCU vendor libraries, but you have not specified what the target is.
